# Download files asynchronously, after that resync

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I tried to download asynchronously certain files, using tips from MSDN and from here, but my attempts usually end with deadlock or errors caused by aplication not waiting for the end of download. Below I pasted sample code that doesn't work but hopefully explains my intentions. I will be grateful for your help.

```
public void SomeMethod() // which must be called synchronously
    {
        // Determine which files to download
    List<FileRequest> fileRequests = Determine();

    var test = DownloadFilesAsync(fileRequests);
    test.Wait();

    // After that do something else with downloaded files synchronously
}

public async Task DownloadFilesAsync(List<FileRequest> fileRequests)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(fileRequests.Select(fileRequest =>
DownloadFileAsync(fileRequest))).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

public async Task DownloadFileAsync(FileRequest fileRequest)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(fileRequest.url,fileRequest.downloadPath).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are mixing sync and async which usually leads to deadlocks. Is `SomeMethod()` an event handler?

Comment: No SomeMethod() isn't an event handler, nor does it refer to element of UI (expecting this as a follow up question).

Comment: If this code is run in the context of a SynchronizationContext which uses the Windows message pump to do its magic then it will deadlock. You should never mix async/ await with blocking code.

Comment: If so, then how can I achive my goal of asynchronous downloading and then using this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `test.Wait();` is blocking the async method

Best practice in using `async` is to use `await` all the way through the method. **Don’t mix blocking and async code.**

```
public async Task SomeMethod() {
    // Determine which files to download
    List<FileRequest> fileRequests = Determine();

    //this will allow the down load to not lock the ui
    await DownloadFilesAsync(fileRequests);

    // After that do something else with downloaded files synchronously
    //...
}

public async Task DownloadFilesAsync(List<FileRequest> fileRequests) {
    await Task.WhenAll(fileRequests.Select(fileRequest =>
        DownloadFileAsync(fileRequest))).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task DownloadFileAsync(FileRequest fileRequest) {
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(fileRequest.url,fileRequest.downloadPath).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Source - [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Okey, but now SomeMethod() needs to be awaited in some other method, which in turn needs to be async. This way asynchronous methods will propagate up, which in turn will certainly break my other methods. Maybe task-based asynchronous pattern just doesn't fit my use case?

Comment: I have used another approach from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6716310/6757641)

Comment: That works in that case because it is being executed in Main. I believe that is the one exception to the rule. did you read the link I included in the answer. `The Main method for a console application is one of the few situations where code may block on an asynchronous method.`